# How to represent a product of cycles in matrix form?

Tags: combinatorics, permutation, group-theory

I have a permutation `a` in a product of disjoint cycles form as follows

$a = {{(1,9,3,7)(2,11,6)(4,8,5,10)}}$

I want to represent it in a matrix form `A` such that

$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\9&11&7&8&10&2&1&5&3&4&6
\end{pmatrix}$

I believe `a` can be defined in Mathematica as

```
a = Cycles[{{1, 9, 3, 7}, {2, 11, 6}, {4, 8, 5, 10}}]
```

How do I convert `a` to `A`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
mat = {Sort @ #, #} & @ PermutationList[a];
MatrixForm @ mat // TeXForm
```

> $ \left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
>  9 & 11 & 7 & 8 & 10 & 2 & 1 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 6):

One idea is to overload [`MatrixForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm) so that it does this for you automatically:

```
Unprotect[MatrixForm];
MatrixForm /: MakeBoxes[MatrixForm[cyc_Cycles], StandardForm] := With[
    {list=PermutationList[cyc]},
    ToBoxes[MatrixForm[{Range@Length@list, list}], StandardForm]
]
Protect[MatrixForm];
```

Then:

```
Cycles[{{1, 9, 3, 7}, {2, 11, 6}, {4, 8, 5, 10}}] //MatrixForm
```

[image]